# How to export the salesforce components rom sfdc.com to my local?

Tags: salesforce, apex

How to export the Apex Class, Apex Trigger, Aura Component Bundle, Custom Object, Lightning Component, Visualforce Component, and Visualforce Page from sfdc.com to my local?

I do not have any ide installed for sfdc.com. I am currently just have access to the developer console.

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform metadata deploys or retrieves to local storage with the Developer Console.

You can achieve this using literally any local IDE, including the currently supported and developed [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [Salesforce Extension Pack](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/set-up-visual-studio-code), the old, unsupported [Force.com IDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_getting_started.htm), or commercial offerings like [Illuminated Cloud](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/).

You can use command-line tools like [`sfdx`](https://developer.salesforce.com/platform/dx) or the [Force.com CLI](https://force-cli.heroku.com/).

You can also write your own [`package.xml` manifest file](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/manifest_samples.htm) and perform a retrieve with [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) or Ant.

You can find examples (for Visual Studio Code) in Trailhead; see for example [Org Development Model](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/org-development-model). Each of the tools named above will offer a slightly different route to achieve this goal, although all of them other than Salesforce DX are ultimately clients of the Salesforce Metadata API and have structural similarities as such.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use https://workbench.developerforce.com
Log in to it using your credential --> Migration --> Retrieve

Here you have to specify a `package.xml` file. For your reference, I am giving the minimum file content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTestSuite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApprovalProcess</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AssignmentRules</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomApplication</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomApplicationComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomLabels</name>
    </types>
    <version>31.0</version>
</Package>
```

You can add the member of any type in this file. Click next and it will download all of the files specified at your `package.xml` file.

In another way, You can integrate salesforce and visual studio code and thus retrieve all the codes and components from salesforce to your local.

Follow [this trail](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quickstart-vscode-salesforce) on trailhead. You will got all of the info there.

You can also follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfAX2ec9py8) tutorial for the complete process.